# Как изменить ответ REST в yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rest

Как можно изменить ответ после того как отправил запрос. К примеру POST, на добавление записи. Как изменить что когда добавит запись, вернет собственный ответ.

Comment: Сервер отвечает клиенту, но не наоборот. Для поддержки этой функциональности придумали websocket, server send events и т.д. А самое из простых и доступных - polling

Comment: то есть нельзя изменить ответ ? То есть если проверку проходит то отправляет один ответ, если нет то другой.

Comment: Хотя возможно я не так понял вопрос. Вы хотите чтобы сервер оповестил клиента об успешности операции вне контекста запроса? (через N времени, без запроса пользователя) Или Вы хотите управлять тем, что ответит сервер по факту: удалось добавить запись или нет? Если второе - просто добавить условие и вернуть ответ. Если первый то изучайте вебсокеты

Answer (score 0):

В ActiveController можно прописать вот это

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['create']);
    return $actions;
}

public function actionCreate(){
    //То что нужно возвращать.
}
```